# Algorithm that displays all the even numbers between 0 and 1000

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

This is how I did it and I think it's wrong

- Step 1: Start
- Step 2: `I = 0`
- Step 3: Input number
- Step 4:

  ```
  while(i <= 1000)
      if(number % 2 == 0)
          display the number
  ```
- Step 5: End

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to do homework. Also, you have not tell us a line of code.

Comment: Please show us that you have at least tried something (i.e. show some code that you have made)

Comment: Look at the Modulo operator.

Comment: ahh , ok i didn't know . sorry tho thanks im i'll try doing it on my own now

Comment: i.e. if(number % 2 == 0) // Its even so print

Comment: You aren't increasing i

Comment: The difference between two consecutive even numbers is always 2.

Comment: don't forget to `i++;`

Comment: thank you guys. really helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Increase i with each iteration in loop

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13651665)

Comment: This provides an answer because, i is not being incremented in loop due to which, the code will be stuck in infinite loop. Why did you think, it is not providing any answer?

Comment: Your answer have been in the low quality post review according its size. And because it doesn't have enough information, it's look like to me more than a comment than an answer. To have a complete answer, provide some explanation to why OP have this behavior, and some code and explanation to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

There is no use of the  variable 'number', just replace the number variable with i in the code, and don't forget to increment i

The code would work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).